# Can a user apply for another public key based on its pseudonym and use the obtained public key in DH key exchange?

Tags: public-key-encryption, diffie-hellman

I have a scenario in which there are three parties: one user,one content provider and a proxy. The data is to be transferred between user and content provider anonymously though the proxy.  I have two questions.
1. If the user has a pseudonym based on its public key, can it apply for another public key?
2. For data confidentiality between user and content provider such that proxy cannot read the transferred contents, Diffie-Hellman key exchange can be used. But can I use the public key obtained in part 1 to get the encrypted data between user and content provider?

Best Regards

Alexandera

Answer (score 0):

Diffie-Hellman is a method for establishing a shared secret between two entities.
So, that's a part of secret key cryptography.

No number of public keys, unless you manage to generate the current shared secret, will get you the information shared between two parties using secret key crypto.  A public key should be matched to, and used with, a private key.  That's public key cryptography.

For part 1, I guess I don't understand what you want to do with the public key other than generate a pseudonym with it, I don't see why not.
Maybe I'm misunderstanding your question but I believe the answer for part 2 is no.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Actually i want to transfer the data anonymously between user and content provider through proxy such that proxy cannot read the contents.